# Using AWS CLI to pull in all possible access levels

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

[image]

Attached graphic is a list of different access levels offered for a particular service. Is there any way I can use the AWS CLI to pull a list of all the different access levels for all different Amazon services?

This is an example picture from 'Alexa for Business' service.

Comment: I don't see how that link resembles my question.

Comment: I misunderstood your question the reference for all cli commands https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ and Alexa for business specific https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/alexaforbusiness/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The image you attached is AWS Console's visualization of some actions, these actions roughly maps to the API calls that you can make from the AWS CLI which you can list

AWS do maintain [a document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html) that list all ***Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys*** for all their services which I believe is what you want

Otherwise, can you clarify your question to show exactly what you want to get from the CLI?

What are the "Access Levels" you are referring to here?

[image: Table]

Comment: So what I want to do is for every Amazon service, list every "Action". the "Access Levels" I was referring to are the same as the "Actions" that are displayed in your graphic.

Comment: @user3299633 non that I know of, other than the roughly equivalent CLI API list and the document that I linked